# Reading & Breaking CSV File in Java:

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am editing this question to be more specific and I've learned some Jave to find the solution to my problem. I have a file in CSV format like this: [image: The CSV File containing the information]
or in excel like this:[image: Same CSV File in Excel]
Now I am using Java program to read the second line of file and separate each Comma Separated Value and write it to console as well as on other output file and it was done easily. Now I'm trying to break the last value of:

S/1,M/1,L/1,XL/1 | 2XL/1,3XL/1,4XL/1,5XL/1 | MT/1,LT/1 (Original)
S/1,M/1,L/1,XL/1,2XL/1,3XL/1,4XL/1,5XL/1,MT/1,LT/1 (Modified using program to remove spaces and replacing the Pipes (|) with comma.

In each value, There is the size name before Forward Slash (/) and its quantity is after that. What I'm trying is using the Forward Slash (/) to separate the size with its quantity. And the problem is that the size may contain the forward slash as well (e.g. 12/BT or 2BT/2x). I've tried many algorithms like reversing the whole array or storing the slash count but not getting the success. The whole code to read file and break the comma separated values into separate columns of file is as following:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ReadFile3c{
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        //Getting File Name
        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name") + ".csv";
        //Creating Stream with File
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        //Applying Buffer Filter
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);


        //Reading First line then Second Line
        String s = br.readLine();
        s = br.readLine();
        s = s + ",";//adding comma at the end of the file
        s = s.replaceAll("\\s",""); //Eliminating Spaces
        s = s.replaceAll("\\|",",");    //Replacing Pipes with comma
        char charArray[] = s.toCharArray();

        //Declaring Strings and variablse for value separating function
        int n = 0;                              //Array Variable
        int m = 0;                              //Array Variable
        String[] inverted = new String[3];      //String to store inverted Commas Values
        String[] comma = new String[10];        //String to store comma Values
        String value = "";                      //Storing character values

        try{
            //Loop to cycle each character of file
            for(int j = 0; j<charArray.length;j++){

                //Inverted comma value separator
                if (charArray[j] == '"') {
                    j++;
                    //loop to gather values b/w invreted comma
                    while((charArray[j] != '"')){
                        value = value + charArray[j];
                        j++;
                    }
                    inverted[n] = value;
                    n++;
                    j++;
                    value = "";
                }else{ 
                    j = j - 1;
                    //comma Value separator
                    if (charArray[j] == ','){
                        j++;
                        //loop to gether values b/w commas
                        while((charArray[j] !=',')){
                            value = value + charArray[j];
                            j++;
                        }
                        comma[m] = value;
                        m++;
                        value = "";
                    }       
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("in inner Exception Block" + ex);
        }

        //declaring variables to storing values
        String name, patternCode, placeSizeQty,width,length,utill,pArea,pPerimeter,totalPcs,placePcs,tSizes;
        name = inverted[0];
        patternCode = inverted[1];
        placeSizeQty = inverted[2];
        width = comma[0];
        length = comma[1];
        utill = comma[2];
        pArea = comma[3];
        pPerimeter = comma[4];
        totalPcs = comma[5];
        placePcs = comma[6];
        tSizes = comma[7];

        //printing all values on Console
        System.out.println("\nMarkerName: " + name);
        System.out.println("Width :" + width);
        System.out.println("Length :" + length);
        System.out.println("Utill :" + utill);
        System.out.println("Place Area :" + pArea);
        System.out.println("Place Perimeter :" + pPerimeter);       
        System.out.println("PatternCode: " + patternCode);
        System.out.println("PlaceSizeQty: " + placeSizeQty);
        System.out.println("Total Pcs :" + totalPcs);
        System.out.println("Place Pcs :" + placePcs);
        System.out.println("Total Sizes :" + tSizes);

        //Creating Output file
        String fileOutput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Output File Name") + ".txt";
        //File Writer
        try{
            //Creating Stream with output file
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileOutput);
            //Applying Buffring Stream
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            //Declaration
            String outputLine = null;
            //Writing Inverted inputs
            for (int u = 0; u <=2 ;u++ ) {
                outputLine = inverted[u];
                pw.println(outputLine);
                System.out.println("Writing: " + outputLine);
            }//end of for
            //writing comma inputs
            for (int t = 0;t <=7  ; t++ ) {
                outputLine = comma[t];
                pw.println(outputLine);
                System.out.println("Writing: " + outputLine);
            }//end of for

            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
            fr.close();
            br.close();                 

        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Output: " + ex);
        }//End of output catch

    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }//end of catch
}//end of catch
}//end of Class
```

And the code to Break the Size and quantity and store it in Double array (Not completed) is as Following:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ReadFileInvert{
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name") + ".csv";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceAll("\\s","");
        s = s.replaceAll("\\|",",");
    System.out.println(s);  

        char charArray[] = s.toCharArray();
        char charArrayI[] = new char[charArray.length + 1]; 

        int j = 0;
        String value = "";

        for(int i = charArray.length; i > 0; i--){
            charArrayI[j] = charArray[i];
            value = value + charArrayI[j];
            j++;                
        }
        System.out.println("1" + value);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Now in simple I just want to Separate the sizes (Which may contains the Forward Slashes) with its quantity (After last slash of each value) and store it in double array Like charArray[sizeName][Qty]. Sorry if i didn't explained my problem well as I'm Learning the Coding. but I'll provide as much info as you want.

Comment: So what program is responsible for loading this CSV file? Forms PL/SQL?
 Database PL/SQL? Also, which version of Oracle database are you using? Another thing: your data doesn't have balanced pairs of double-quotes - presumably that's a typo in how you've posted the data?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The thing is now that my request have been rejected by our database management by saying that its not possible in the system. Now i am creating a structure in JAVA to read that file and separate all the values. I'm very sure and confident that I'll sort that problem and will forward the solution to my developers. again thanks for your response.

Comment: Sounds like you need a new database team.

Comment: Yep. But unfortunately its not that easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So, after the hard work of whole day, I've found the following solution to my problem:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ReadFileInvert2{
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter File Name") + ".csv";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceAll("\\s","");
        s = s.replaceAll("\\|",",");
        System.out.println(s);  
        char charArray[] = s.toCharArray(); 
        int x = charArray.length - 1;
        charArray[x] = ',';

        int no = 1;
        int size = 1;
        int qty = 2;
        String sizeS = "";
        String qtyS = "";
        //String resSet[][] = new String[4][2];
        String resSize[] = new String[20];
        String resQty[] = new String[20];
        int slashNo = 0;
        String value = "";


        for (int j = 1; j < charArray.length; j++){
            int n = j;
            if (charArray[j] == ','){
                j++;
            }
            while (charArray[j] != ','){
                if (charArray[j] == '/') {
                    slashNo = j;
                    //j++;
                }
                value = value + charArray[j];
                //System.out.println(value);
                j++;
            }   
            for (int k = n;k < slashNo; k++ ) {
                sizeS = sizeS + charArray[k];
                //System.out.println(sizeS);
            }
            for (int l = slashNo + 1; l < j; l++ ) {
                qtyS = qtyS + charArray[l];
                //System.out.println(qtyS);
            }
            resSize[no] = sizeS;
            System.out.println(resSize[no]);
            resQty[no] = qtyS;
            System.out.println(resQty[no]);

            System.out.println("Size is: " + resSize[no] + ", and Qty is: " + resQty[no]);

            no++;
            slashNo = 0;
            sizeS = "";
            qtyS = "";
        }
        String fileOutput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Output File Name: ") + ".txt";
        try{
            FileWriter fw =  new FileWriter(fileOutput);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            String outputSize = null;
            String outputQty = null;

            for (int t = 1; t < no; t++) {
                outputSize = resSize[t];
                outputQty = resQty[t];
                pw.println(outputSize + " = " + outputQty);
                System.out.println("Writing: "+ outputSize + " = " + outputQty);
            }
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
            fr.close();
            br.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Output " + ex);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }   
}
}
```

Now its in Generic form but will improve it later. But still its working fine. Thanks for your Help stack overflow Community.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered looking at the CAD software export to see if there is a solution on the file creation side? Or is this file coming from a third party?

Comment: Yes I did, but didn't found any option to change the formatting of the file into different type.